# Does Google index images declared using 'srcset'?

Tags: html, web-crawlers, images, googlebot

As of Chrome 40, the `srcset` attribute is supported, but will Google index the images within it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I set up a test page [here](http://www.undistraction.com/srcset_test.html).

Using Webmaster Tools' Fetch As Google feature, I saw that Google doesn't pick up the image declared in the `img`'s `srcset` attribute:

[image]

However, adding the JavaScript Polyfill [Picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) I was very surprised to see that Google now does pick up the image declared in the `srcset` attribute. This means Google is running the JavaScript.

[image]

It's also interesting to note that Google gets the visitor rendering wrong - a visitor does see the second image.

I've submitted the page to be indexed and will add the result here.

Comment: As far as I know, Fetch as Google is JS enabled. And yes Google does utilize its JS crawler to crawl sites. But somebody tested it is much less frequent as disabled one

Comment: Did you ever find out if adding Picturefill allowed *Google Images* to index the larger version?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 2):

Update from Februari 2018. It seems like Google is still picking the src attribute initially. I added the higher resolution to the Image XML sitemap and it looks like Google is picking up those.

Answer (score 1):

On a website I've published some years ago, I'm using `srcset` attribute on images but it seems google is not picking up those images (although it indexes the one on `src` attribute).

Check this [query `site:psicoanalista.albertofernandez.com.ar` on Google Images](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=site:albertofernandez.com.ar&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRlsSf-sLUAhXGg5AKHaYCDXQQ_AUIBigB&biw=1352&bih=644).
As you can see, only the smaller images (which are the ones I specified in `src` attribute as a fallback) are being indexed.

I'd like to find some official Google statement on this topic.