# Does html5 picture tag affect SEO?

Tags: images, html5

I know when using `<img>` tag, the alt & title are using for SEO. But is `<picture>` tag is better for SEO with the attribute srcset? If yes how?

Answer (score 5):

It won't have a positive effect on your SEO. For search engines, as for screen readers, the alt tag and the on-page caption are the big factors. The `<picture>` tag is more of a developer technique rather than an SEO technique. It is no more semantic than the `<img>` tag, since crawlers know that both represent an image. Furthermore, the last child of the `<picture>` tag is the `<img>` tag, to provide a fallback. Your `<img>` tag should still contain the alt text. The search engines will still find it.

This post, from this very message board, is worth looking at:

[Does Google index images declared using 'srcset'?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83251/does-google-index-images-declared-using-srcset)

Thus, it is particularly important to include that fallback `<img>` tag, with your preferred image, when using `<picture>` in your code.