# Can you indicate to Google Images which image it should index from srcset?

Tags: seo, google-search, images, google-image-search, image-search

Related Github issue: https://github.com/browniebroke/gatsby-image-gallery/issues/844

So I'm using Gatsby and an image gallery. The gallery generates two images, a thumbnail and the gallery image. The thumbnail is a low resolution file and the gallery image is high resolution.

```
<img srcset="example-320w.jpg 320w,
       example-480w.jpg 480w,
       example-800w.jpg 800w"
   sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
      (max-width: 480px) 440px,
      800px"
   src="example-800w.jpg" alt="responsive web">
```

Is there any way to tell google images to skip the low res thumbnail and instead take the gallery image? Or for the sample code above: Is there any way to tell which image google chooses?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to request that Google chooses a specific image. Yes, you can predict which one Google will index.

As Trey touched on, Googlebot will always index the image in your `src` attribute and ignore `srcset`.

See more information in this related question, where it was empirically tested:
[Does Google index images declared using 'srcset'?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/83262/54214)

Answer (score 1):

Google will use the image in your standard `<img src="">` element

Answer (score 0):

I think that yes you can, you need to use JSON+LD schema.

This is basically what tells Google the metadata of your webpage.

After this change, the image listed there will be the one that Google shows in their results.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/article